# JQuery + Javascript + Web Service not working on mobile devices

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

I am building a shopping cart that displays a popup via Javascript.

It then accesses a web service via Javascript and display the product info using JQuery SimpleModal

I think the Jquery part works, because the Modal displays. and the Javascript works as well.

but when it tries to access the web service, nothing happens.

It works fine on desktop, but i need it work on Mobile devices.

Is there something I am missing?
Can a c# web service run on mobile devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,What do you mean?

Comment: I am using C# and web services.  When i access the site on my mobile phone, it does not work.  It seems the web services is not being called on mobile devices.